# could not find implicit value for parameter c: anorm.Column[Float] Play Framework Scala

Tags: scala, anorm

I cannot parse float value in play framework, It gives me a compilation error.
    So from database I get value as float but it can not determine value 
     as float and gives error of anorm of float.

Error it gave is is like

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXhb0.png)

My code is like :

```
package model
import anorm._
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current

case class Contact(id: String, VehiclePositionLattitude: Double, 
  VehiclePositionLongitude: Any)

object Contact {

  def all={

    DB.withConnection { implicit connection=>

      SQL("Select VehicleJourneyUID,VehiclePositionLattitude,VehiclePositionLongitude 
        from csv_output where  VehicleJourneyUID in (31356)")().map{ row=>
        Contact(
          id=row[String]("VehicleJourneyUID"),
          VehiclePositionLattitude=row[Double]("VehiclePositionLattitude"),
          VehiclePositionLongitude=row[Float]("VehiclePositionLongitude")
        )
      }.toList

    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also take the approach of reading it as a Float and converting it (if safe to do so?) What version of play are you using as it compiles ok on my side. Also I see you have defined Longitude as Any - surely that would be Float (or Double)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use implicit Reads and Writes for Float? or how about validate it with BigDecimal data type even it appears as Float at SQL Database.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `Reads` is for Play JSON, not Anorm